# Creating a sqldatareader class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, sqldatareader

I am struggling to create a class that i can access from other classes that will be accessible throughout my application.  I am new at creating classes and appreciate any logical tips.  Ultimately, I would like to access "checkpoint1-5" values in "LUSDschoolDates" as "chk1", "chk2", etc.  Not sure if i am populating the data properly or better to use a List<>??  The underline portion indicates the area where i am struggling (which is basically telling me i cant access) and where i like it to work. The goal in the project is to create a back end admin page where a user can insert datetime data, and these values need to be accessible throughout the entire app..

```
public class checkpoint
{
    public string checkpoint1 { get; set; }
    public string checkpoint2 { get; set; }
    public string checkpoint3 { get; set; }
    public string checkpoint4 { get; set; }
    public string checkpoint5 { get; set; }
}

public class myCheckpoints
{
    public static string Checkpoints()

    {

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lusdMembership"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT chk1, chk2, chk3, chk4, chk5 FROM checkpoints", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                checkpoint c = new checkpoint();
                c.checkpoint1 = reader["chk1"].ToString();
                c.checkpoint2 = reader["chk2"].ToString();
                c.checkpoint3 = reader["chk3"].ToString();
                c.checkpoint4 = reader["chk4"].ToString();
                c.checkpoint5 = reader["chk5"].ToString();  
            }
            return Checkpoints();
        }

    }
}


public class LUSDschoolDates
{

    public static DateTime chk1 = new DateTime(checkpoint.checkpoint1);

}
```

USING A LIST (it doesnt seem to like "return checkpoint;")
     public class checkpoint
    {
        public string checkpoint1 { get; set; }
        public string checkpoint2 { get; set; }
        public string checkpoint3 { get; set; }
        public string checkpoint4 { get; set; }
        public string checkpoint5 { get; set; }
    }

```
public class myCheckpoints
{
    public List<checkpoint> GetDate(string chDate)

    {

        List<checkpoint> Checkpoints = new List<checkpoint>();
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lusdMembership"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT chk1, chk2, chk3, chk4, chk5 FROM checkpoints", connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                checkpoint c = new checkpoint();
                c.checkpoint1 = reader["chk1"].ToString();
                c.checkpoint2 = reader["chk2"].ToString();
                c.checkpoint3 = reader["chk3"].ToString();
                c.checkpoint4 = reader["chk4"].ToString();
                c.checkpoint5 = reader["chk5"].ToString();

            }
            return checkpoint;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You create a new instance of checkpoint  but dont return it. Shouldn't it be
"return checkpoint;" rather than "return CheckPoints();"? Also, if you are expecting multiple objects to be returned from the DB then you will need to add them to some sort of collection (e.g. List<Checkpoint>)

Comment: I posted an edit using a list (as i originally done actually) but it doesn't like "return checkpoint;"??

Comment: `checkpoint` is the type, not the list. You should return `Checkpoints`. You never *add* any checkpoints to the list though, so the list will be empty. This is actually a C# syntax question, not an ASP.NET or SqlDataReader question. BTW you should probably use proper casing for type and field names to avoid confusion, eg, `Checkpoint` for the type, `checkpoints` for the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a class for you which connects to a SQL database and returns check points as a `List<T>` where T is a class called `CheckPoint`.You were also missing logic to open and close the SQL connection which I've included:

```
public class CheckPoint
{
    public string CheckPoint1 { get; set; }
    public string CheckPoint2 { get; set; }
    public string CheckPoint3 { get; set; }
    public string CheckPoint4 { get; set; }
    public string CheckPoint5 { get; set; }
}

public class MyCheckpoints
{
    public List<CheckPoint> GetCheckPoins()
    {
        List<CheckPoint> checkpoints = new List<CheckPoint>();

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["lusdMembership"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT chk1, chk2, chk3, chk4, chk5 FROM checkpoints", connection);
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CheckPoint c = new CheckPoint
                    {
                        CheckPoint1 = reader["chk1"].ToString(),
                        CheckPoint2 = reader["chk2"].ToString(),
                        CheckPoint3 = reader["chk3"].ToString(),
                        CheckPoint4 = reader["chk4"].ToString(),
                        CheckPoint5 = reader["chk5"].ToString(),
                    };
                    checkpoints.Add(c);
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return checkpoints;
    }
}
```

**And here's how you can call it from ASP.NET:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

        MyCheckpoints myCheckpoints = new MyCheckpoints();
        List<CheckPoint> checkPoints = myCheckpoints.GetCheckPoins();
        int count = checkPoints.Count;
    }
}
```

*If you want to make `MyCheckpoints` reusable accross different projects you should create a new project in Visual Studio of type Class Library and copy this class inside the Class Library.*